[Jazzy][Rviz2] joints of type continuous are not rendered in Rviz2
I tried to modify a urdf file of a robot from humble to work with jazzy. Unfortunately the joints are not rendered in rviz anymore. I tried another example with the same result.
In rviz I get following error:
No transform from [roll_front_left] to [base_footprint]
I have no problems in gazebo harmonic. There the robot is fine and I can control it with teleop_twist_keyboard.
I use the basic launch file from nav2_minimal_tb4_simulation simulation.launch.py
  <joint name="wheel_front_left_joint" type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="-0.0 0.02 -0.040" rpy="0.0 1.57 0.0"/>
    <parent link="roll_front_left"/>
    <child link="wheel_front_left"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
  </joint>


Problem is solved, I used the config.rviz file from the example. With a new empty one it works.

Today I got it working. I added the continuous joints to the DiffDrive Plugin Tag in my urdf file. With a reboot I cleaned up the topic "/robot_description" and it worked.
 <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-diff-drive-system" name="gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive">
      <left_joint>wheel_back_left_joint</left_joint>
      <right_joint>wheel_back_right_joint</right_joint>
      <wheel_separation>0.575</wheel_separation>
      <wheel_radius>0.13</wheel_radius>
      <max_linear_acceleration>2</max_linear_acceleration>
      <min_linear_acceleration>-2</min_linear_acceleration>
      <max_angular_acceleration>3</max_angular_acceleration>
      <min_angular_acceleration>-3</min_angular_acceleration>
      <max_linear_velocity>0.5</max_linear_velocity>
      <min_linear_velocity>-0.5</min_linear_velocity>
      <max_angular_velocity>2.0</max_angular_velocity>
      <min_angular_velocity>-2.0</min_angular_velocity>
      <topic>/cmd_vel</topic>
      <odom_topic>/odom</odom_topic>
      <tf_topic>tf</tf_topic>
      <frame_id>odom</frame_id>
      <child_frame_id>base_link</child_frame_id>
      <odom_publish_frequency>30</odom_publish_frequency>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-joint-state-publisher-system" name="gz::sim::systems::JointStatePublisher">
      <joint_name>wheel_back_left_joint</joint_name>
      <joint_name>wheel_back_right_joint</joint_name>
      <joint_name>roll_front_left_joint</joint_name>
      <joint_name>roll_front_right_joint</joint_name>
      <joint_name>wheel_front_left_joint</joint_name>
      <joint_name>wheel_front_right_joint</joint_name>
      <topic>joint_states</topic>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

I hope this is the intended solution.
